# Volume by using disc method

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The area under $y=3x-x^2$ between $x\in[0,2]$ is rotated about the $y$-axis and I need to find the volume of the generated solid.

Using the cylindrical shell method, I found the volume to be $8\pi$.

Using the disc method, I get a washer and the integral becomes
$$
v=3\pi\int\sqrt{9-4y}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
However, I am not sure what the bounds of the integral is supposed to be. If I use

$$
v=3\pi\int_0^{2.25}\sqrt{9-4y}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
Then I get the volume to be $\frac{27}{2}\pi$ which I guess is wrong and does not agree with the answer I got from cylindrical shell method. What am I doing wrong in my disc method? What the bounds of the integrals are supposed to be?

Comment: Your disk method is wrong.  The integrand needs to be the difference in the areas of two disks.

Comment: @Randall I can not see how it is wrong. I get a washer. My our radius is $\frac{3+\sqrt{9-4y}}{2}$ and my inner radius is $\frac{3-\sqrt{9-4y}}{2}$. Using the difference of two squares $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, I get $\text{outer radius}^2-\text{inner radius}^2=3\sqrt{9-4y}$ and hence, I think my disk method is correct.

Comment: If $y<2$, the outer radius is $2$, not $\frac{3+\sqrt{9-4y}}{2}$. Draw a picture.

Answer (score 1):

First we ought to split into cases depending on whether $y$ is bigger than or smaller than $2$. For $y$ below $2$, the outer radius of the washer is $2$, while for $y>2$, the outer edge of the washer is given by the graph.

The inner radius of the washer is in either case
$$
\frac{3-\sqrt{9 - 4y}}{2}
$$
while for the upper part, the outer radius is given by
$$
\frac{3+\sqrt{9-4y}}{2}
$$
The volume is thus
$$
V = \int_0^{2.25}A(y)\,dy\\
= \int_0^2\pi\left(2^2-\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{9-4y}}{2}\right)^2\right)\,dy\\ + \int_2^{2.25}\pi\left(\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{9-4y}}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{9-4y}}{2}\right)^2\right)\,dy\\
= \int_0^2\pi\left(y-\frac12+\frac32\sqrt{9-4y}\right)dy + \int_2^{2.25}3\pi\sqrt{9-4y}\,dy
$$

Comment: This is a great example to show how you need several different tools to attack the same general problem.